# How to inject global parameters into Minitest tests?

Tags: ruby, minitest

This is my test:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
class Foo < Minitest::Test
  def test_it
    // here
  end
end
```

This is my `Rakefile`:

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |test|
  test.libs << 'lib' << 'test'
  test.pattern = 'test/**/test_*.rb'
  test.verbose = false
  test.warning = false
end
```

I want to have an ability to pass some global configuration parameter from `Rakefile` to all unit tests. The only way I found so far is through a global variable from `test__helper.rb`. But Rubocop complains about global variables and I agree with it. Are there any Minitest-friendly solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest solution I can think of is through ENV-variables. [(Docs)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/ENV.html)

You just call the tests with:

```
SOME_VARIABLE=some_value rake test
```

And in minitest you just do

```
ENV.fetch('SOME_VARIABLE', default_value)
```

While the default is optional (but recommended, otherwise you get an error when you want to run the tests without parameter).

I think this is the cleanest solution because unit tests should essentially always work in the same way. The **only** reason I can think of where you want to change the behaviour of the Unit tests is per envionment (like letting the CI Server run the specs that take longer than usual, having other settings for capybara between different machines etc)

Comment: My variable is not of a primitive type (like text). It's an object.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on what you are trying to achive? Maybe give an example? If it is just an Object, why can't it be instantiated within the test itself? 
If you introduce something like that, you probably also introduce shared state/a shared resource within your test, which is what you usually want to avoid (since it often makes your tests order dependant when incorrectly used). 
With some context on what you are actually trying to achive I could probably help you better.